# не получается переопределить значение объекта

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты

```
formatQuestions(data){

    data.questions = 'something'

    return data.questions
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Ответ

Не много изменил ваш вариант, но и в прошлом виде он отлично работал!

```js
let myTestObj = {
    testParam: 1
}

console.log("Preview", myTestObj)

// Функция для замены
const changeObj = prevObj => prevObj.testParam = 126
// Выполняем замену
changeObj(myTestObj)

console.log("Now", myTestObj)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь код опять же не сработал но ты подталкнул меня на идею и я смог исправить ошибку